# How do I know the extensions installed in the user's browser when logged into my site

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a site. When the user logs in, I want to check if certain browser extensions are installed.

For example: If ad-blocker is installed, the site should not work for the user.

Comment: u can check which browsers run your web site there is no additional option for that getting certain extensions installed in the browser.

Comment: Question re-written to increase clarity - you can revert this if you aren't happy with the change. On a side note though, the question will more than likely be closed as it is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for SO. Please take the [tour] to learn what type of questions can and cannot be asked here.

Answer (score 1):

So you cannot check what extensions are installed, but in the case of adblock, you can leverage the change of the actual DOM structure to determine if adblock is installed.

See example:

HTML:

```
<div class="heightTest">
    <div class="adBanner">
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('.heightTest').height() > 0) {
        alert('No AdBlock');
    } else {
        alert('AdBlock Detected');
    }
});
```

So in this instance we can deduce that adblock is installed because if we check the parent container (`.heightTest`) it has no height as a result of the child element (`.adBanner`) has been deleted by adblock (or a similar extension).

Comment: You did not understand me
I want to check the extensions in general